# C - Copying array of strings

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I have problem with pointers. I'm trying to copy the contents of array 'names' to array 'self.names'.
In the loop the pointer points to first element when I'm printing the value of pointer, but when I'm giving it as argument to strcpy its pointing to the third element.
What I'm doing wrong?

Argument.h:

```
#ifndef ARGUMENT_H
#define ARGUMENT_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Argument{
    char **names;
};
struct Argument Argument_new(char**);

#endif
```

Argument.c:

```
#include "argument.h"

struct Argument Argument_new(char **names){
    struct Argument self;
    size_t namesc=0;
    char **names_start=names;
    while(*names++){
        namesc++;
    }
    self.names=malloc(namesc*8);
    for(names=names_start;*names;names++){
        printf("%s\n",*names);
        *self.names=malloc(sizeof(*names));
        strcpy(*self.names,*names);
    }
    names=names_start;
    printf("%s\n%s\n",self.names[0],names[0]);
    printf("%s\n%s\n",self.names[1],names[1]);
}
```

main.c:

```
#include "argparse/argparse.h"

int main(int argc, const char **argv){
    char *a[]={"abc","def","ghi",NULL};
    Argument_new(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sizeof(*names) does not give you the right value, it will alway give 1. You need to.get the stringlength.

Comment: What is the 8 in `namesc*8`?

Comment: @lalala Actually it always gives `sizeof(char *)`.

Comment: @DYZ namesc*8 is namesc*sizeof(*names).
sizeof(*names) is always 8 so there is 8 :)

Comment: `sizeof(*names)` is _not_ always 8. It is, what it is.

Comment: `sizeof(*names)` is size of pointer to array of chars and AFAIK pointer size is 8

Comment: The size of a pointer is not always 8. It depends on your system.

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On every iteration of the loop, you're copying the current string to `*self.names`, i.e. `self.names[0]`, the first element in the list.  So when you print `self.names[0]` only the last thing you copied appears there, i.e. the last string in the `names` list.

You need to keep track of which name you're on and copy into the relevant array member.

Also, `sizeof(*names)` gives you the size of a `char *`, not the length of the string it contains.  You want `strlen` for that, and be sure to add 1 for the null byte at the end.  Similarly, when allocating the list, don't use the magic number 8 but use `sizeof(*names)` instead:

```
int i;
self.names=malloc(namesc*sizeof(*names));
for(i=0,names=names_start;*names;names++,i++){
    printf("%s\n",*names);
    self.names[i]=malloc(strlen(*names) + 1);
    strcpy(self.names[i],*names);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for fast and good answer.
Can you tell me one more thing?
Can I use pointers instead of variable 'i' there?

Comment: @DeBos You can use `*(self.names + i)` which is equivalent, but the former is more readable.

Comment: I thought about something like:
Change every `self.names[i]` to `*self.names` and give the `self.names++` in the correct place and then remove the 'i' variable.
Is something like that possible?